# Want to to upload and display a picture in xe:formTable control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I've been mucking around trying to get combination of xp:fileUpload and xe:multiImage for display but no luck.  I'm not married to a solution using these two controls and will accept any valid approach.

I would like to provide the upload/display picture functionality withing a xe:formRow in an xe:formTable if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to show a list of images that are uploaded to the document, I'd suggest to use a **xp:repeat** instead.

In the **xe:formRow** you can add the following to add an upload control (in edit mode only) and a list of attached images. Assumption is that the XPage is bind to a document datasource, I've used "images" as the name of the rich text item used to store the images:

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" value="#{document1.images}"
    rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}">
</xp:fileUpload>
<xp:repeat id="repeatImages" rows="30" var="image">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getAttachmentList("images");}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:image url="#{javascript:image.getHref()}" id="image1"></xp:image>
</xp:repeat>
```